# extract data using regex in splunk

Tags: regex, rex

i have data as `"{\"data\":{\"correlation_id:\"51g0d88f-3ab8-4mom-betb-b31ed6e1662z\",\"u_originator_uri` in _raw. i want to extract values of correlation_id as CorrelationId4

Comment: Best to use a JSON parser to easily extract a field, such as `JSON.parse(_raw).data.correlation_id` will return the value of `correlation_id`.

Comment: i want splunk query to extract data. as i have user role so can not extract data in json format

Comment: What do you mean by `correlation_id as CorrelationId4` ?

Comment: i want to extract value of correlation_id and save it into field CorrelationId4

Answer (score 0):

Best to use a JSON parser to easily extract a field, such as `JSON.parse(_raw).data.correlation_id` will return the value of `correlation_id`.

I do not have splunk to test, but try this if you want to use the rex splunk command with a regular expression:

```
rex field=_raw "correlation_id:.\"(?<CorrelationId4>.*?).\""
```

Detail docs at https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/8.1.1/SearchReference/Rex

Comment: i tried your splunk query but it does not give value